# Wordpress on Azure as Subdirectory

Tags: domain, directory

A client gave me access too `devblog.azurewebsites.net` where I was supposed to install the theme I developed and configured using WordPress.

Now that the setup is complete, the site must be moved to `http://clientdomainname.com/blog`.

How can I move the domain name without losing my theme and setup?

Comment: You need to simply create a CNAME record: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

Comment: clearly not a wordpress development question. Original place was correct.